# Как в TextFormField узнать позицию курсора?

Tags: flutter, dart

При ошибочном вводе мне нужно оставлять курсор на том же месте, а он все время возвращается в начало строки. Поэтому перед вводом я хочу сохранять позицию курсора, и при ошибке возвращать позицию на сохраненное место. Как получить позицию курсора?

Answer (score 0):

Придумала такое решение:

```dart
onChanged: (String text)
{
  var textDouble = double.tryParse(text);
  var selection = _controller.selection;//Сохраняем текущую позицию курсора

  if (textDouble != null)
  {
    if (textDouble > 1000)//Ошибочный ввод
      {
        _controller.text = oldText;//Возвращаем старое значение
        _controller.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
            TextPosition(offset: selection.baseOffset - 1));//Оставляем курсор на сохраненном месте
        return;
      }
    _controller.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
        TextPosition(offset: _controller.text.length));

    oldText = _controller.text;//Пересохраняем старое значение
  }
}
```